# Проблема с подключением к БД SQL Server из WCF-службы

Tags: .net, entity-framework, wcf

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь работать с данными БД SQL Server в WCF-службе, хостом для которой является Windows-служба. Использую Entity Framework. Код приведён ниже.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Domain.Entities;

namespace Domain
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public string cs;
        public Context(string connection_string)
        {
            Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connection_string;
            cs = connection_string;
        }
        public DbSet<Customers> cust { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Orders> ord { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cars_In_Stock_Table> cars { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Domain;
using System.Configuration;
using Domain.Entities;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Repository_EF
{
    public class Repository
    {
        private Context context;
        public Repository()
        {
            context = new Context(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
        }
...
public DataTable GetOrdersByPassport(int passport)
        {
            var r=(from i in context.cust join j in context.ord on i.Passport equals j.Passport_of_cust  where i.Passport==passport select new{j.VIN, j.Type_of_payment, j.Credit, j.Order}).ToList();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc0 = new DataColumn("VIN");
            table.Columns.Add(dc0);

            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Type_of_payment");
            table.Columns.Add(dc1);

            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Credit");
            table.Columns.Add(dc2);

            DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Order");
            table.Columns.Add(dc3);

            DataRow dr;
            foreach (var k in r)
            {
                dr = table.NewRow();
                dr["VIN"] = k.VIN;
                dr["Type_of_payment"] = k.Type_of_payment;
                dr["Credit"] = k.Credit;
                dr["Order"] = k.Order;
                table.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

Метод GetOrdersByPassport вызывается в OperationContract:

```
public string OrdersByPassport(int passport)
        {
            Repository repository = new Repository();
            Query_result qr = new Query_result();
            qr.data = repository.GetOrdersByPassport(passport);
            return (qr.ToString());
        }
```

Получаю:
1) тестовый клиент WCF - "При получении сведений о поставщике из базы данных возникла ошибка. Ее причиной могло быть то, что Entity Framework использует неверную строку подключения. См. подробные сведения во внутренних исключениях и удостоверьтесь в том, что используется правильная строка подключения.";
2) исключение: "Поставщик не возвратил строку ProviderManifestToken" и "Для этой операции необходимо соединение с базой данных 'master'. Не удается создать соединение с базой данных 'master', поскольку исходное подключение базы данных было открыто, и из строки соединения удалены учетные данные. Укажите не открытое соединение.".
При присоединению к процессу службы выполнение останавливается на строке

```
var r=(from i in context.cust join j in context.ord on i.Passport equals j.Passport_of_cust  where i.Passport==passport select new{j.VIN, j.Type_of_payment, j.Credit, j.Order}).ToList();
```

Строка подключения:

```
<add name="connection_1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\Projects; AttachDbFilename=g:\My projects\Cars_project_3\DB\Cars_DB_5\Cars_DB_5.mdf; Initial Catalog=Cars_DB_5; Persist Security Info=true;"/>
```

Просьба помочь.

Comment: а откуда Вы взяли такую строку соединения?

Comment: Существует ли файл БД? Есть ли у сервиса права на его чтение? Не открыта ли это БД в другом инстансе SQL сервера (помните, что у localdb создается отдельный инстанс для каждого пользователя)?

Comment: Да, файл там, где нужно. В других экземплярах использование этой БД не нашёл (искал вручную). Как определить права сервиса на чтение не очень понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаете в EF строку подключения - но я не вижу, чтобы вы при этом указали провайдера БД. А для EF его имя тоже важно: ведь EF способен работать с любой СУБД.

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
public Context() : base("name=connection_1") {}
```

Это позволит EF увидеть в файле конфигурации не только строку подключения, но и имя провайдера. Возможно, именно этого и не хватало для подключения к БД.

И еще одна вещь, которую стоит проверить. Добавьте параметр `Integrated Security=True` в строку подключения - не зря же EF ругается на отсутствие учетных данных в строке подключения...

Comment: Павел, спасибо за ответ! У меня указан поставщик данных: providerName="System.Data.SqlClient". Попробовал добавить Integrated Security=True - не помогло. Есть ещё момент: всё работало, когда подключался с такой же строкой подключения из ASP.NET MVC-приложения.

Comment: Прочитайте мое сообщение еще раз. Поставщик данных у вас, на самом деле, не указан.

Comment: Добавил Provider=sqloledb. Выдаёт : "Ключевое слово не поддерживается: \"provider\".".

Comment: Зачем вы его в строку подключения добавили?

Comment: В книге Троелсена есть пример, где это пишется в строке соединения. А куда надо?

Comment: Прочитайте мой ответ еще раз.

Comment: Сделал как вы предложили: переделал конструктор в пустой, не принимающий аргументов. По-прежнему ошибка.

Comment: Значит, ошибка была не в этом.

Comment: Может ли быть, что служба не имеет каких-то прав при обращении к экземпляру SQL Server и/или к конкретной БД?

Comment: Ошибка поменялась. Теперь это "При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Произошла ошибка Local Database Runtime.Указанный экземпляр LocalDB не существует". Сервер существует, удалённые подключения разрешены.